# What is wisdom in vipassana meditation?

Tags: theravada, stages-of-the-path

Having seen that anger disappears after noticing attraction and aversion of the mind towards thoughts, attraction and aversion have disappeared.  Feel like there is no core on mind objects. Is that anatta?

Comment: Well, if you wanted to call this something, then wisdom would be suitable. However, I would allow the conventions of chronology to take further course. Let the passage of time reveal its activity.

Answer (score 1):

A wisdom excluded from the Dhamma-discipline is not a perfect wisdom. Therefore, there is no liberation where the Dhamma and Discipline are absent. It is in the Supreme Buddha’s Dhamma that the perfect concentration is described. It is that Dhamma that the contemplations are described as this is the first contemplation (Dhyāna), this is the second contemplation, this is the third contemplation, and this is the fourth contemplation. If one develops wisdom, it has to be a wisdom that is being developed praising the Dhamma and the Discipline. This is wisdom in vipassana meditation. In order to come to this Wisdom, one needs to sever and totally obliterate the three bonds of Nichcha (thinking that one can maintain a permanent state of mind), Sukha (believing that which is happiness/good can be maintained), aththa (thinking that this is a stable, fulfilled state of mind). If “atta” is “in control” or “has essence”, and the opposite of that is the anatta in Tilakkkhana: “one is helpless in this rebirth process”.

Answer (score 0):

Question is whether the stage is anatta. --The answer lies hidden in itself in writing this question on this site. Still the questioner is present then how can it be "anatta. These signs are all of the tranquil  mind to which we are unknown since many lives.Furthermore the mind itself ,being very clever to sustain itself, ask or give false feeling of the very big big states . It goes no telling ,now its ok, you have reached the destination , this is what is anicca,anatta, wts the meaning in continuing . But not be foolished by tricky mind and go on practising. The experience/wisdom of anicca/anatta ,whenever it happens,you will not even on this site also to ask question also. perhaps  you may be then be resolving difficulties/guiding the path goers.

Answer (score -2):

Good question!

Vipassana, the tranquil mind, is the core.

When emotions arise, the tranquil mind observes and assesses before the conscious is involved. Instant emotional, physical and intentional reaction is an uncultivated reaction - which has a tendency to result in more, similar reactions (from the one in question or uncultivated others involved).

In an uncultivated individual the emotions rule the self. This is the result of lack of understanding of Anatta and somehow the individual is putting conscious effort into the stagnation of their naturally dynamic emotions.

Emotions are naturally dynamic and a result of environmental influence, which is also dynamic - so in that sense Anatta is applicable. If one cultivates the practice of unbiased observation, the result will be an understanding and application of Anatta to the heart. The tranquil mind will recognise the burning heart and dualise the self. When the self becomes two, the emotions don't rule the mind and the mind doesn't rule the emotions.

Cultivate in harmony